# C# IsWindow(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto()) always failing

Tags: c#, .net

I'm actual working on a little ScreenMonitoring which sends an EMail if a new Visible Window pops up. My problem is right now this part:

```
Console.Write("                                       GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name: " + GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name + "\n");
Console.Write("          Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name): " + Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name) + "\n");
Console.Write("IsWindow(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name)): " + IsWindow(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name)) + "\n\n");

if (IsWindow(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name)))
{
    listView_Windows.Items.Add(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name);
}
else
{
    aDeleteWindows.Add(new myAVP {
        Name = "",
        Handle = i
    });
}
```

The output of my Console.Writes is like:

```
                                       GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name: notepad++
          Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name): 84883296
IsWindow(Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(GeneralSettings.aItemsToAdd_Windows[i].Name)): False
```

The reason my Program is failing is because it is always running through the "else" part because IsWindow is always false. So can someone help me out, how can I check if the process called (in this case) notepad++ is still an visible and opened window? Besides the process name i also got the process id. My research was the result that i have to use the Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto function with the process name to get the ptr hwnd. Is this right, or where could be my mistake?

The returned value of the marshal function (in this case): 84883296 doesn't says me anything that I cold get why IsWindow always fails.

So Far, thanks in advice.

Comment: Why on the earth `IsWindow` should accept a `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto` ? And how have you defined `IsWindow`?

Comment: Defined by: [DllImport("user32.dll")] > here should be an carriage returne < [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] > here should be an carriage returne < static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd); - I did some research where ppl posted that u could use it therefore. I was confused first too, but I'm actual not that long in C#. Could u give me a tipp how I could get a solution instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written by Dieter:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

and then

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "title of your window");

if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // Present
}
```

`IsWindow` is used to check if an handle of a window (for example returned by `FindWindow`) is still valid (the window still exists)

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. When I wanted to implement your way of doing this, I found a few lines code where I use the System.Diagnostic.Process library which has the method Process.MainWindowHandle. I already used it before too (I don't get why I didnt saw this earlier) and decided to try it first. And well it's almost done. The part we talked about in this Question seems to work fine. I'll (ofc) try your part when I should mention any kind of problems by this lines. So Far thanks alot. I really apreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You want FindWindow or EnumWindows and not BOOL WINAPI IsWindow(_In_opt_  HWND hWnd) feeded with a Handle to a string.